# Django unittest - Unable to create table

Tags: mysql, django, unit-testing

I'm trying to write simple test for my django application. But it fails every time when i run `./manage.py test`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/home/tyler/projects/django/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-package/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/home/tyler/projects/django/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/home/tyler/projects/django/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 30, in run_from_argv
super(Command, self).run_from_argv(argv)
File "/home/tyler/projects/django/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "/home/tyler/projects/django/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 74, in execute
super(Command, self).execute(*args, **options)
File "/home/tyler/projects/django/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 441, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/home/tyler/projects/django/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py", line 90, in handle
failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
File "/home/tyler/projects/django/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 210, in run_tests
old_config = self.setup_databases()
File "/home/tyler/projects/django/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 166, in setup_databases
**kwargs
File "/home/tyler/projects/django/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/runner.py", line 370, in setup_databases
serialize=connection.settings_dict.get("TEST", {}).get("SERIALIZE", True),
File "/home/tyler/projects/django/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/creation.py", line 368, in create_test_db
test_flush=not keepdb,
File "/home/tyler/projects/django/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 120, in call_command
return command.execute(*args, **defaults)
File "/home/tyler/projects/django/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 441, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/home/tyler/projects/django/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 179, in handle
created_models = self.sync_apps(connection, executor.loader.unmigrated_apps)
File "/home/tyler/projects/django/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 317, in sync_apps
cursor.execute(statement)
File "/home/tyler/projects/django/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "/home/tyler/projects/django/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 97, in __exit__
six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
File "/home/tyler/projects/django/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 62, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql)
File "/home/tyler/projects/django/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 124, in execute
return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
File "/home/tyler/projects/django/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 205, in execute
self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
File "/home/tyler/projects/django/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
raise errorclass, errorvalue
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1005, "Can't create table 'test_products.#sql-4b8_e9' (errno: 150)")
```

I thought the problem was with MySQL engine, but I checked it in MySQL workbench it is InnoDb engine. May be someone had the same problem.

Comment: which version of django you are using?

Comment: I'm using django 1.8.2

Comment: did your migration works ?

Comment: It works. But test creating new db for itself.

Comment: can you post your models here.in django 1.8 The MySQL backend no longer creates explicit indexes for foreign keys when using the InnoDB storage engine, as MySQL already creates them automatically

Comment: decide problem by recreating migrations files for my app!

Comment: You should make that an answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the exact same problem, when running `manage.py test` on a django app that I ported from Django 1.5 to Django 1.8.

```
./manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>

...

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1005, "Can't create table 'test_xxxx.#sql-6c1_6c' (errno: 150)")
```

Just as Sergii V. notes, the solution has to do with migrations. In my case there was no migrations file at all (that feature didn't exist in Django 1.5).

So the solution was running

```
./manage.py makemigrations <appname>
```

After that, tests work fine:

```
./manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.014s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```